# Clear an Angular form upon Submission

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-forms

I'm trying to clear the form, but keep facing some issues. How can I clear the form on a submit?

**HTML**

```
<form id="contact" class="contact-form" ng-submit="sendMail()" novalidate ng-controller="QuoteCtrl">
<div class="message"></div>
 <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 animated hiding" data-animation="slideInLeft">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="nameform form-control input-lg" placeholder="name" ng-model="message.contactName" required>
  </div>     
</div>

<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-custom up form-button" value="Send Message">
```

**Angular**

```
app.controller('QuoteCtrl', ['$scope', '$interval', '$http', 
function($scope, $interval, $http) {
    $scope.message = {};
   $scope.sendMail = function () {
      $http.post('/send/sendQuote', $scope.message).
        success(function(data) {
         $scope.message = data.message;
         console.log($scope.message);
         $scope.message = {};
      });
   }
}]);
```

What are the main techniques to clear forms, including setPrestine()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it.it will work fine

```
$http.post('/send/sendQuote', $scope.message).
        success(function(data) {
         $scope.message = data.message;
         console.log($scope.message);
         $scope.message.contactName=null;
      });
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work for me. Is there any other ways?